# The maximum of several affine functions is a polyhedral function

Tags: convex-analysis, affine-geometry, polyhedra

A function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto (-\infty,\infty]$ is polyhedral if its **epigraph** is a polyhedral, i.e.

$$\text{epi}f=\{(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} | \ \ C\left( \begin{matrix} x\\ t \end{matrix} \right)\leq d\} $$

where $C\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times (n+1)}$ and $d\in \mathbb{R}^m$.

Ex:

$$f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^p  \text{max}_{1\leq i\leq m}(a_{ij}^Tx+b_{ij})$$

> How to understand this is a polyhedral function?

I know "$\text{max}_{1\leq i\leq m}(a_{ij}^Tx+b_{ij})$" is pointwise maximum (fixed $j$). But how to understand a polyhedral from the definition?

Comment: Do you know how to get the epigraph of a sum/max of functions in terms of their epigraphs?

Comment: not quite understand, I am weak in this part. I am weak in these complicated function

Comment: See: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/l_lqp_poly_fcns.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's review:

1. A function is polyhedral if its epigraph is a finite intersection of closed halfspaces.
2. The epigraph of $\max(f_1,\dots,f_m)$ is the intersection of the epigraphs of $f_1,\dots,f_m$.
3. The epigraph of $x\mapsto (a_{ij}^Tx+b_{ij})$ is a closed halfspace.

Combining the above yields the answer to your question.